# Transparent web icons on dark backgrounds have white outline and look low quality

Tags: images, transparency, file-format, web-safe

I usually make my images transparent using an internet online tool like *LunaPic* (Images like member ranks, buttons etc.)

The thing is that on light backgrounds they are looking fine but on dark ones (like black) they're not looking sharp.

Example on light gray background:

[image]

Example on dark background:

[image]

**I don't have Photoshop.**

**Is there something I can do to fix it?**

Comment: I'd first want to know if you made these images? If you did, it would only be a matter saving the image differently. Otherwise, your best bet might be Gimp. There may be some more automatic tools that can do this, but Gimp should give you enough control to make sure it comes out clean. Recreating it might even be easier for you, since it's only circles and text.

Comment: This should help: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+to+remove+background+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Is your final image a PNG or a GIF?

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to remove the background from an image using a quick way and worse.. using a free/cheap tool online. Problem with this methods and tools is that they do a poor job performing this tasks.

If you want a clean work you need the proper tools to do it. If you don't have Photoshop, I recommend downloading the free trial (30 days). If you are looking for a free alternative, all I can think about is Gimp and although not as powerful as Photoshop, it's able to do it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This isn't very helpful

Comment: Hi Ruben! You could explain to the original poster how to do it, which file format to use, etc. The original poster doesn't have Photoshop and if you know how to explain the solution using Gimp, that will certainly be helpful and be a practical free alternative!

Comment: Hi there! I don't know how to do it in Gimp, but I know it's possible. In Photoshop I can explain how to do it if he downloads the free trial.